# ProtocolBuffer object ByteSize is wrong

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

I have the following method:

```
void ConnectionManager::SendAll()
{
for (int t = 0; t < (int)m_Connections.size(); ++t)
{
    if (m_Connections[t].socket != INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        // Create the object
        MessageID message;
        message.set_type(MessageID::Type::MessageID_Type_PLAYERDATA);

        for (int i = 0; i < (int)m_Connections.size(); ++i)
        {
            if (m_Connections[i].playerData.username() != google::protobuf::internal::kEmptyString)
            {
                auto temp = message.add_playerdata();   
                temp = &m_Connections[i].playerData;
            }
        }

        if (message.playerdata_size() > 0)
        {
            // Serialize to byte array
            int size = message.ByteSize();
            void* buffer = malloc(size);
            message.SerializeToArray(buffer, size);

            Send(m_Connections[t].socket, buffer, size);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Now the problem lies at the end of this method, at the line:

```
int size = message.ByteSize();
```

I know that the data is loaded correctly (or it should be at least) but the size isn't right. It should be 30 and it returns 2. I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.

The data in m_Connections is available and should be reached by pointer temp. I think that, for some reason, the data is lost from the "message" object but I don't know how to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> auto temp = message.add_playerdata();   
> temp = &m_Connections[i].playerData;
> ```

These lines look wrong. `add_playerdata()` returns a pointer. That means that the second line is just setting `temp` to some other pointer, not doing anything to the message which `temp` points at. It's more obvious if you write out the type rather than use `auto`:

> ```
> MessageID::PlayerData* temp = message.add_playerdata();   
> temp = &m_Connections[i].playerData;
> ```

Maybe you wanted to do this instead:

> ```
> *temp = m_Connections[i].playerData;
> ```

However, I do not see how this bug would lead to `ByteSize()` being 2. It looks like `ByteSize()` should only be 2 if you haven't added any players to the message, but then `playerdata_size()` would be zero, so you wouldn't get to the serialization step at all.

Comment: Well the thing is that temp is a new item in a vector of type PlayerData* in the MessageID object "message". What I wanted to do in the line you copied was to assign the data from a vector I have created to the vector that is used in the MessageID object. I'll try your ideas.

Comment: Well, I haven't checked the data yet but apparently the line: `*temp = m_Connections[i].playerData;` solved the crash. Could you perhaps explain why?

Comment: Well, this is basic C... `temp` is a pointer, `*temp` is the thing the pointer points at. If you write `temp = &foo;`, you're only changing the pointer, to make it point at `foo` rather than at whatever it was pointing at before. Since you don't even use `temp` again after that, this has no effect. On the other hand, when you write `*temp = foo;`, you are copying the *value* of `foo` into the thing that `temp` points at.